# For Eigen SparseMatrix, what does innerIndexPtr() and outerIndexPtr() exactly represent?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am working with Eigen::SparseMatrix and I am having trouble understanding the meaning of `innerIndexPtr` and `outerIndexPtr`. The explanation at [the official page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__SparseQuickRefPage.html) is very vague to me. Intuitively, I thought `innerIndexPtr` is the row indices for non zero elements and `outerIndexPtr` is the column indices for the non zero elements but apparently that's not the case. Please see below example,

```
std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> triplet;

triplet.emplace_back(0, 0, 10);
triplet.emplace_back(2, 0, 11);

Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(3, 3);

A.setFromTriplets(triplet.begin(), triplet.end());

std::cout << A.innerIndexPtr()[0] << std::endl; // prints 0
std::cout << A.innerIndexPtr()[1] << std::endl; // prints 2
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << A.outerIndexPtr()[0] << std::endl; // prints 0
std::cout << A.outerIndexPtr()[1] << std::endl; // prints 2, but I thought it should print 0
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << A.valuePtr()[0] << std::endl; // prints 10
std::cout << A.valuePtr()[1] << std::endl; // prints 11
```

Can someone explain to me what `innerIndexPtr` and `outerIndexPtr` exactly represents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You matrix looks like this:

```
    (0) (1) (2)
(0)  10   0   0
(1)   0   0   0
(2)  11   0   0
```

Internally, a sparse consists of four compact arrays:

> - `Values`: stores the coefficient values of the non-zeros.
> - `InnerIndices`: stores the row (resp. column) indices of the non-zeros.
> - `OuterStarts`: stores for each column (resp. row) the index of the first non-zero in the previous two arrays.
> - `InnerNNZs`: stores the number of non-zeros of each column (resp. row). The word inner refers to an inner vector that is a column for a
>     column-major matrix, or a row for a row-major matrix. The word outer
>     refers to the other direction.

(See [Sparse matrix manipulations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html))

Your matrix is stored as:

```
      Values: 10 11
InnerIndices:  0  2

 OuterStarts:  0  2  2
   InnerNNZs:  2  0  0
```

To quote the manual:

> Low-level API
>
> ```
> sm1.valuePtr();      // Pointer to the values
> sm1.innerIndexPtr(); // Pointer to the indices.
> sm1.outerIndexPtr(); // Pointer to the beginning of each inner vector
> ```

Therefore, `valuePtr()` returns `[10, 11]`, `innerIndexPtr()` returns `[0, 2]`, and `outerIndexPtr()` returns `[0, 2, 2]`.  This should explain the result you observe.

---

Some explanation on the `OuterStarts` array: the columns numbered 1 and 2 consist of zeros.  This doesn't affect the outer index.  The column numbered 1 starts at position 2 and ends at position 2.  The column numbered 2 also starts at position 2 and ends at position 2.  The fact that they consist entirely of zeros just means they are zero-sized.  I agree that the explanation for `OuterStarts` in the manual is a bit misleading.  Think of "the fist non-zero" as the past-the-end element.

Comment: From what you explained for `OuterStarts`, shouldn't it be `0 null null` instead? There's no non zero in column 1 and column 2. Or maybe I still don't fully understand it yet...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how `3` is related to explaining why `outerIndexPtr` isn't `0 null null`.

Comment: @user3667089 Sorry, I screwed up with my previous comment.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

Eigen uses CSC (compressed sparse column) format (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)).

`outerIndexPtr()[i]` indicates the index into other arrays where i-th column starts. It ends at `outerIndexPtr()[i+1]`, where the next column begins. If these thwo indices are equal to each other, the column is empty.

`innerIndexPtr()` is an array of row indices of elements,
and `valuePtr()` is an array of corresponding values.

So, to illustrate it, this code iterates through i-th column

```
int k_start = A.outerIndexPtr()[i];
int k_end   = A.outerIndexPtr()[i+1];

for (k = k_start; k < k_end; k++) {
    int j = A.innerIndexPtr()[k];
    double v = A.valuePtr()[k];
    // v is value of the element at position (j,i)
}
```

---

All above is for column-major storage, which is default in Eigen. For row-major, exchange row <-> column in the description above.